# Convert AM/PM datetime to 24 hour when both formats present in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, time

I have a messy table with a column called `date_time`. It has values in both AM/PM and 24 hour format (see example below). I am creating a new table using the *messy table* with the following code:

| ID | date_time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/24/2022 7:08:00 PM |
| 2 | 1/24/2022 17:37 |
| 3 | 1/24/2022 9:36:00 PM |
| 4 | 1/24/2022 22:14 |

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE (ID INT, date_time datetime)

SELECT
  ID, date_time
INTO NEW_TABLE
FROM MESSY_TABLE
```

Desired conversion:

| ID | date_time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/24/2022 19:08 |
| 2 | 1/24/2022 17:37 |
| 3 | 1/24/2022 21:36 |
| 4 | 1/24/2022 22:14 |

Comment: DateTime is just stored in the DB, you can change the format when you select it for UI layer or something.  Unless the original table is not datetime format.

Comment: *"The date_time columns has records where the date_time is displayed in both AM/PM and 24 hours"* then it's not a `datetime`, it's a string based data type, such as `varchar`. You could, however, try a couple of `TRY_CONVERT`s with style codes.

Comment: is it guaranteed that the string either (i) ends with AM/PM or (ii) in military format?

Comment: To expand on Thom A's comment.  try_convert() will return a NULL if the conversion fails,   Just for fun https://dbfiddle.uk/Ju9G-MAE

Comment: Dates have no format, they're binary values. How they're displayed is entirely up to the client application. If `date_time` is really a `datetime` field, there's nothing to convert. That would mean that the client application is truly evil and randomly changing the display format. Or that `CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE (ID INT, date_time datetime)` has nothing to do with the real table

Comment: At least post code that actually reproduces the problem. What you posted doesn't have any data so wouldn't return anything. Include both the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT ... VALUES` clauses so others can reproduce the problem

Comment: The post is pretty clear to me, the dates are stored as strings, need to be converted to datetime "data type".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) with appropriate `style` for date portion of the input string. SQL Server seems to handle 12 and 24 hours format time as expected:

```
select id, date_time, convert(datetime, date_time, 101) as date_time_value
from (values
    (1, '1/24/2022 7:08:00 PM'),
    (2, '1/24/2022 17:37'),
    (3, '1/24/2022 9:36:00 PM'),
    (4, '1/24/2022 22:14'),
    (5, '1/24/2022 05:37')
) as t(id, date_time)


-- id  date_time               date_time_value
-- 1   1/24/2022 7:08:00 PM    2022-01-24 19:08:00.000
-- 2   1/24/2022 17:37         2022-01-24 17:37:00.000
-- 3   1/24/2022 9:36:00 PM    2022-01-24 21:36:00.000
-- 4   1/24/2022 22:14         2022-01-24 22:14:00.000
-- 5   1/24/2022 05:37         2022-01-24 05:37:00.000
```